# How to show scroll bars in android's WebView

Tags: android, html, android-webview

Is it possible to show scrollbars for scrollable html elements in android's WebView? How to do it?

Comment: try `webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

in your `onCreate()` method  : try this :

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.your_web_view_layout); 

    browser = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.your_webview);
    WebSettings mWebSettings = browser.getSettings();
    mWebSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    browser.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
    browser.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
    browser.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me. Enabled both scroll bars, tried outside and inside, overlay and inset, changed scroll bar size and fading - nothing helps: scrollbars are missing.

Comment: Finally I found out, that scrollbars are actually shown BUT in white color (have no idea why - this is on Android 6.0.1, webview 48, no special theme in the app) and since most pages are with white background, the scrollbars are not visible. The solution was to specify dimmed color shape in `android:scrollbarThumbVertical`. Crazy Android.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in your xml layout:

```
<WebView
    android:id="@+id/myWebView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@color/primary_container_on_primary"
    android:scrollbarSize="2dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
WebSettings WebSettings12 = browser.getSettings();
WebSettings12.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webview.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webview.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(false);
webview.loadUrl("https://google.com");
```

Answer (score -1):

For me helped

```
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
```