# Android WebView- Scroll bar not visible after few scrolling inWebView

Tags: android, webview

In webView after a few scrolls, the webView default scrollbar gets disappears.
This is my webView code:

```
<WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/webview"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:clickable="false"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:scrollbarThumbVertical="@android:color/holo_blue_bright"
android:scrollbarTrackVertical="@android:color/darker_gray"
android:scrollbars="vertical"></WebView>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to show scroll bars in android's WebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7938300/how-to-show-scroll-bars-in-androids-webview)

Comment: @animusmind No, the scrollbar is showing but after few scroll it gets disappear

Comment: have you tried with the code logic? sometimes with xml this issue comes.

Comment: @animusmind Yes but the issue remains the same

Comment: Could you show what you tried with the code?